# How can I dynamically draw/scale buttons?

Tags: java, button, for-loop, methods

This is rather simple but I cant seem to figure it out, I'd like to define how much space I have on the Y axis, and define how many buttons I want and the gap between each button, it should figure out the height of each button and place the button.

ex:

```
public void drawButtons(int buttons, int gap, int ySpace, int x, int width){

    for(int i = 0; i < buttons; i++){
        //Workout the y and the height here!
        int height = (ySpace / buttons) - (gap * (buttons - 1))

        //Other stuff here!

        g.fillRect(x, theY, width, height);
    }

}
```

the x and the width of the button isn't a problem, I would later edit this method to draw text in the center of the button and use the `mousePressed` method to determine if the button was clicked.

Comment: You have `n` buttons in `y` space and want to space them evenly?

Comment: Yes, with the gap in between each button

Comment: My program isn't an application, its a game so I wanted to make custom buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reinventing the wheel.

1. Don't try to draw your own buttons.

   - Use Java controls like [`JButton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html). See [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html).
   - Alternatively, make your own subclasses of [`JComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) or use [`JLabel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html).
2. Don't place them on the screen manually. Use a [`LayoutManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). Placing them on the screen yourself is too difficult is much harder than learning how the `LayoutManager` api works.

   - I recommend using [`GroupLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html) if you need to have controls that automatically resize.

I know this seems more difficult now, since you have to learn about how all these things works, but I promise you *these tools exist for a reason... because they make everyone's life easier, not harder*. You will finish your game faster by learning how these things work than by just diving in using `paintComponent`.

Comment: A JButton looks like this: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jbutton&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMIrYCw8NGkxwIVRy4aCh2_cwpZ&biw=1517&bih=714&dpr=0.9#imgrc=DYhpHV5BkZeqQM%3A, I want my button to just be a simple button, ex: http://thedroidcafe.com/wp-stuff/uploads/2014/05/Flappy-Bird.jpg Or something that looks like a minecraft button, simple image with text that creates a sound when clicked, I can do all this but I need to figure out where the buttons should be and It will also help so that if youre playing in a different resolution, it will scale the buttons!

Comment: @GenaratedPixelz Then make a subclass of `JComponent` and override `paintComponent` to draw the button like that, then place it in the `JPanel` using a layout manager. Let the layout manager control it's location, only worry about telling your button how to draw *itself*.

Comment: Could you please give an example of how I could use this?

Comment: @GenaratedPixelz I already did. Click the many links in my answer.

Comment: They don't really help :/

Comment: @GenaratedPixelz Don't worry about your game for right now. Just look at their examples and figure out how they work. Come back to your game once you understand them.